# Open new Bootstrap lightbox after closing current lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap modal lightbox in a project. Here are my requirements: I have a code to open the lightbox1.html

```
<a href="/lightbox1.html data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

Inside the lightbox there are several conditions. For some special condition, I show the message to the user that 'Your request can't be forwarded right now, Would you like us to email us to get more details.'

then there are two buttons:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>  
<a class="btn btn-primary">Yes</a>
```

If user presses 'No' then current lightbox would be closed but I want that if the user presses 'Yes' then it would close the current lighbox and opens a new lightbox 'email.html', so I want a proper code for the Yes button to close current lighbox (lightbox1.html) and open a new lightbox (email.html).

Comment: @Geo but what should I write inside href attribute to close the current lightbox and open a new one

Comment: you will probably need to write a custom jQuery for this rather than using the existing toggle buttons of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some jQuery in there along the lines of this :

```
$("#btnYes").click(function() {
  $("#modal1").modal('hide');
  $("#modal2").modal('show');
});
```

Obviously you would need to set an id/class as per what you want each to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the lightbox content is static and described on the same page then we can use the code mentioned by you but in my case, content is loading by different pages i.e. lightbox.html and email.html so it would not work. Anyway, I have solved my problem by hiding the lightbox.html content and loading the email.html content on click function in a same lightbox i.e. lightbox.html. In other words, I have changed the content rather than changing the lightbox.

Comment: Glad you solved it. You can also add remote options via jQuery too.